# C-record in AWS Route 53- is path allowed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want to create an record where

https://dev75.key.pre-prd.com/

get Route traffic to

https://api.key.pre-prd.com/service2

is it possible to create record with the path at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Route 53 is a **Domain Name Service** (DNS).

Basically, a DNS server translates a domain name (`example.com`) into an IP address. So, when you type `example.com` into a web browser, your computer uses DNS to convert it into an IP address, then establishes a connection with a computer on that IP address.

This is similar to how your phone has a list of **Contacts**. You select a contact by their *name*, and the phone calls their *telephone number*.

DNS only refers to the name at the start of a URL (after `http://` or `https://`) but *before* the first slash. This is the **Domain Name**. Anything *after* the domain name is sent to the recipient computer to tell it what page to retrieve. Thus, **it is not possible to create a DNS Name that includes a path**.

In your situation, you would need a web server listening on `https://dev75.key.pre-prd.com/` that *forwards* the requests to `https://api.key.pre-prd.com/service2`. This cannot be done with DNS alone.